# What exactly does it mean for something to be "Visually Kinaesthetic"?

Tags: meaning

I came across this term but I'm not sure what it means exactly, I can't think of any examples that this phrase would make sense with.

Comment: It sounds to me like a phrase used by art critics who have heard of ' visual kinesthesia', not understood it and used the words anyway. I might be wrong. Can you say where you saw the term, give a url if possible and provide a complete sentence for context. Thanks.

Comment: It means that the art gives your eyes an image that your brain interprets as being in motion, even though the picture is stationary. This is a kind of _optical illusion_.

Comment: I found a mention of this phrase in a book about invertebrate vision: Invertebrate Vision, by Warrant and Nilsson.  Seems to fit well with @deadrat's Answer.  Looks like fun reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinesthesia (the sense of body movement) and proprioception (the sense of body position) are senses that give us the recognition of where we are and where we are going.  This involves balance, recognition of muscle tension, the estimates of the magnitude and direction of forces on the body, etc.  It turns out that these so-called senses rely on feedback from the other senses, and in particular optical information from our vision.  Our vision gathers information about the outside world and about our relationship to that world, and that latter part of vision is called **visual kinesthesia**.

Visual kinesthesia is what gives us the sense of the "flow of movement" as we move toward the fixed point in our visual field, that is the target upon which we fix out eyes as we make it our destination.  For more information check [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=oohtO-ShSIgC&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=%22visually%20kinesthetic%22&source=bl&ots=1TzqDeBFxB&sig=OGNwNQEj6Sezspk9EJw-Tlkhf3U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwBGoVChMIoMKU7JjVxwIVyDI-Ch0u7wML#v=onepage&q=%22visually%20kinesthetic%22&f=false).